# Index pandas series by an hour

Tags: pandas

In my code I am currently doing the following kind of operation with Pandas:

```
ser = oldser.dropna().copy()
for i in range(24):
    ind = ser.groupby(ser.index.hour).get_group(i).index
    ser[ind]=something
```

This code copies a series, and then for takes each hour separately and does something to it. This seems very messy though - any ways to nicely clean it up?

What I really want, is something analogous to

```
series['2011']
```

which gets all data from 2011, but instead

```
series['2pm']
```

getting all data at 2pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you want to do the groupby operation once, a slight refactor:

```
g = ser.groupby(ser.index.hour)
for i, ind in g.indices:
    ser.iloc[ind] = something
```

But most likely you can do a transform or apply (depending on what something is):

```
g.transform(something)
g.apply(something)
```

Comment: Thanks - the refactor makes sense. Couldn't figure out the transform apply approach  when I looked into it at first. I was hoping there was some nice syntactic sugar.

Comment: @thebigdog you need something to be a function for transform/apply, worth checking out the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: This does seem like the best solution. I have something that works now, although I'd still like something 'cleaner ;-)'

Comment: @thebigdog completely depends on the something whether or not you can do apply/transform ! :)